# JS split string and return index of each split

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I want to split text on a certain regex and also to have an index of where that split starts in the original string.
On a simple example:

```
"bla blabla haha".splitOnRegexWithIndex(whitespaceRegex)
```

Needed output is

```
[["bla", 0], ["blabla", 4], ["haha", 11]]
```

Regex here can be anything, not just whitespace, so delimiter isn't fixed size.

Splitting is done on regex. I don't want to use `indexOf` to find `"blabla"` in the starting string because that would be O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity which is not acceptable in my scenario.

Comment: It's a bit of a hack, but [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) can take a callback function which provides the index of the match. You could use the callback to construct the array along with that index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible implementation based on [`.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec):

```js
function split_with_offset(str, re) {
    if (!re.global) {
        throw "no no no no :(";
    }
    let results = [];
    let m, p;
    while (p = re.lastIndex, m = re.exec(str)) {
        results.push([str.substring(p, m.index), p]);
    }
    results.push([str.substring(p), p]);
    return results;
}

console.log(split_with_offset("bla blabla haha", /\s+/g));
console.log(split_with_offset("   ", /\s+/g));
console.log(split_with_offset("", /\s+/g));
```

Caveat: The regex must have the `g` flag set.

Comment: @CodeManiac Thanks; I was fooled by the synopsis on MDN, which only says "*the `exec()` method returns an array*".

Comment: I guess you also need to handle leading/trailing delims, as in `   blah   `

Comment: @georg Try `" blah ".split(/\s+/)`. Empty entries are the expected result for `split`.

Comment: @melpomene: yeah, it depends on what you expect from it ;) Don't know if empty matches are of any use for the OP.

Comment: This is the best answer here, thank you. It would be great if it didn't return empty matches, but I can just filter them out so not a big problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) and it's callback

```js
let str = `bla blabla haha`
let data = []

str.replace(/\S+/g,(m,offset)=>{
  data.push([m,offset])
})

console.log(data)
```

Comment: In a way that's the opposite of what OP is asking for. Your code uses the regex to determine what to extract; `split` uses the regex to determine what to throw away.

Comment: I don't understand that comment. What I mean is that OP's example code asked for `splitOnRegexWithIndex(whitespaceRegex)`, but to use your code you have to invert the match, i.e. use a `nonWhitespaceRegex`. Another minor difference is that `split` never returns an empty array.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. Yea, melpomene is right, i just gave whitespace as an example. "Regex here can be anything, not just whitespace". So I can't specify what I want to keep, but what I want to split on. How would you extract it given the regex on which you need to split?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) to retrieve an interator with indices:

```js
const s = "bla blabla haha";

for (let m, reg = /\S+/g; m = reg.exec(s);) {
  console.log(m[0], m.index);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why I can't dump the object with properties in stack snippets?

Comment: You mean `console.log(m)` and see `m.index`? Because `m` is an Array and `console.log()` of an Array does not show additional properties.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I see that. Wonder why they'd use an array for this when there are properties set.

Comment: That's not a split operation, that's an extract. For example, split never returns an empty array.

Comment: Sure. I'm not exactly sure what OP wants--there's only one example provided, without regex, and the prototype method thing seems a little silly to me, so I removed it.

Comment: Hi, thanks, this is pretty close to what's needed. Just, regex to split on can be anyting, I just gave whitespace as an example. I can see how this works when you specify a regex for what you want to keep, but if you specify a regex on which you want to split, how would that be done?

Comment: I messed around with some code, but ultimate [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57295578/6243352) seems best to me.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can first use `String.split()` with your regular expression, and then use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the resulting array. Something like this:

```js
function splitOnRegexWithIndex(str, regexp)
{
    let offset = 0, tmp;

    return str
        .split(regexp)
        .map(s => (tmp = offset, offset += s.length + 1, [s, tmp]));
}

console.log(
  JSON.stringify(splitOnRegexWithIndex("bla blabla haha", /\s/))
);
console.log(
  JSON.stringify(splitOnRegexWithIndex("bla blabla haha", /b/))
);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

However, and like a **warning**, you should note that the previous approach only works nicely if the splitting token has `1` character length. But, the idea can be generalized if we use [capturing groups](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups) on the splitting regular expression, and then [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on the resulting array as shown next.

```js
function splitOnRegexWithIndex(str, regexp)
{
    let offset = 0;

    // Add capturing group to the regular expression.
    regexp = new RegExp("(" + regexp.source + ")");

    // Split the string using capturing group and reduce
    // the resulting array.
    return str.split(regexp).reduce((acc, s, idx) =>
    {
        if (idx % 2 === 0)
            acc.push([s, offset]);

        offset += s.length;
        return acc;
    }, []);
}

console.log(
  JSON.stringify(splitOnRegexWithIndex("bla   blabla  haha", /\s+/))
);
console.log(
  JSON.stringify(splitOnRegexWithIndex("abaaagbacccbaaddytbax", /ba+/))
);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you'r regex is not global, you'll get two parts, the one before and the one after the first match.

```js
function splitOnRegexWithIndex(string, regex) {
  var results = [], cnt = regex.global ? Infinity : 1, m, offset = 0;
  
  while (cnt-- && (m = regex.exec(string))) {
    results.push({
      index: offset,
      text: string.slice(offset, m.index)
    });
    offset = m.index + m[0].length
  }
  
  results.push({
    index: offset,
    text: string.slice(offset)
  });

  return results;
}

console.log(splitOnRegexWithIndex(`bla blabla haha`, /(\s+)/g));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution.  It's not pretty but it works when the delimiters are a simple set of single characters.  Won't work with look-aheads, look-backs, etc.  Could be modified easily to cope with classes.  Limited, but it does some of the job.

```
function splitWithOffset(s) {  
    const wanted = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'.split('');    
    const elemf = () => ({text: '', offset: 0});
    const list = [elemf()];  
    let next = list[0];

    s.split('').forEach((c, i) => {
        if (wanted.includes(c)) {
            if (next.text === '') next.offset = i;
            next.text += c;
        } else {
            next = elemf();
            list.push(next);
        }
    });

    return list.filter(elem => elem.text !== '');
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `map` and `indexOf` to know the position in the original string:

```
 String.prototype.splitOnRegexWithIndex = function(regex){
    var splitted = this.split(regex);
    var original = this;

    return splitted.map(function(){
               return [this, original.indexOf(this)];
           });
}
```